# Persistent group chat or some other form of reliable 2-way communication with a group

Tags: steam

Playing with friends is the best. Individually messaging 20 people when you're looking for a game is the worst. Is there a way to make a persistent group chat (you rejoin it after restarting Steam) or some other way to reliably communicate with multiple people over Steam?

Comment: Create a large group chat and Hibernate instead of shutting down?

Comment: @jeffreylin_ that would require far too much work from all involved, I may as well herd them into a 3rd party IM group chat.

Comment: That would work, but what if they leave when they get bored? That also requires much maintenance on your part.

Comment: Use IRC or SE chat instead?

Comment: @MBraedley I've considered trying to talk my friends into using SE chat, but the rep requirement kinda scares them off (yes, I know, it's only 20, but that seems like a *lot* to someone if it's standing in their way, and they're new to SE).

Comment: Use group announcements to notify your friends of when, where and what is planned. For chatting, you might want to use chat applications.

Comment: I recommend using IRC, if you have the means.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure is this would work for you, but id say to try and make your own steam community group https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=2092-QLZX-8453#create and then use the chat function in there.

Also, is suggest making it private/invite only if you JUST want your friends. I havent tested the persistence of this, but i know the chatroom will always be available...

Comment: Ive read that the chat room is permanent, but im not sure about persistence... additionally, if it isnt, you can still post to the group itself as comments for persistence!

Comment: That would at least eliminate the problem with having to personally invite people back in after they restart Steam.